# XML data from MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, web, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to show the result from select in xml. But when I list a result with blob image, I get the following error: **This page contains the following errors:
error on line 33 at column 27: Encoding error
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.**

I don't know what's wrong...the field type in MySQL is blob.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');
 mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'test');mysql_select_db('test');


        if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] != '')
        {
            if($_GET['id'] == '0'){$sql = 'SELECT * FROM CDUsers';}
            else{$sql = 'SELECT * FROM cdusers WHERE id = '.$_GET['id'];}
        }

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($num != 0)
    {?>
        <CDUsers>
        <?php while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                {?>
                    <user>
                    <id><?php echo $user['id'];?></id>
                    <name><?php echo $user['name'];?></name>
                    <surname><?php echo $user['surname'];?></surname>
                    <location><?php echo $user['location'];?></location>
                    <email><?php echo $user['email'];?></email>
                    <password><?php echo $user['password'];?></password>
                    <gender><?php echo $user['gender'];?></gender>
                    <foto><?php echo $user['foto'];?></foto>
                    <tipo><?php echo $user['tipo'];?></tipo>
                    </user>
        <?php   }//?>
        </CDUsers>
    <?php }else
                {?>
                    <CDUsers>
                    <user>
                    vazio
                    </user>
                    </CDUsers>
    <?php       }
?>
```

Comment: given that line 33 is "{?>", and has no column 27, where are you actually getting the error in this code?

Comment: just to preempt the copied and pasted comments about the evils of `mysql.*` the OP is free to use whatever functions he likes

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yes....exactly this code... :S

Answer (score 0):

without knowing where it's literally flagging the error, I'm going to guess it's because you're serving `text/xml`, but the data you return is not valid XML. An XML document needs an xml version indicator (`<?xml version="1.0"?>`) and a doctype (`<!doctype ......>`) before the document data. It looks like you're skipping that part and jumping straight to an XML fragment  consisting of `CDUsers` elements.